# a matrix with determinant $1$, what can be said about the column $(a \space c)^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ be a matrix with determinant $1$, what can be said about the column $(a \space  c)^T$?

from the condition we have $ad-bc=1$, so do I have to conclude something from this condition only?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing we can conclude with certainty, if we know nothing about $b$ and $d$, is that the column is not $(0,0)^T$.

In every other case, we can find $b$ and $d$ such that the determinant is $1$. For example, if $a\ne 0$, we can choose $b=0$ and $d=1/a$. If $a=0$ but $c\ne 0$, we can produce an example along similar lines.

**Remark:** There could be other answers, if conditions are put on the matrix entries. For example, if all entries are restricted to be **integers**, then we can conclude that $a$ and $c$ are **relatively prime**, that is, they have no common divisor greater than $1$,

Answer (score 2):

As the determinant is non-zero , the columns are linearly independent. So from that we can say that the first column is not a scalar multiple of the second